# Centering view on a moving position in SFML

Tags: c++, view, sfml

I want to use sf::View in SFML in order to change the position of the view, such that the player sprite is always in the center of the screen. Thus I want to write a function which allows me to input a set of coordinates and thus center the screen around those coordinates. In addition I want to be able to set a limit to this, such that when the player reaches the side of the map, that axis of the camera stops following the player, as it has reached a "limit". How do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use `sf::View`'s `setCenter` to center the camera on a point.   sf::Vector2f newPos = player.getPosition(); if (/* check map boundaries here... */) { /* set newPos here... */ } view.setCenter(newPos);

Comment: I solved the problem with help from game design from stack exchange. I ended up using view.reset(sf::FloatRect) although I understand it is also possible with view.setCentre. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

The function you need is called sf::RenderWindow::setView . 
Do something like this:

```
sf::RenderWindow window (sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Test");
sf::View view ();
view.setCenter (/*Set Center here*/);
window.setView (view);
```